# In JointJS I get the error property html does not exist on type 'typeof shapes'

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I want to develop an app with JointJS. I am following a tutorial found on the official JointJS website (http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements). So far I have only written one line:

```
joint.shapes.html = {};
```

and I'm already getting an error:

"property html does not exist on type 'typeof shapes'"

What is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I've found the answer. Because actually I'm not using javascript, I'm using typescript. And in Typescript you can't dynamically add an attribute to an object, so if shapes doesn't contain an property named html, you can't add it to it dynamically.